# Shopping Cart Price Rules

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

I am trying to create a shopping cart rule where a customer can purchase up to 5 of the same products that are set to a specific attribute at the same price as 1.  In my conditions I have selected the attribute ‘sample’ then I want to select if qty in basket is less than equal to 5 to apply the rule.  But the quantity in cart option is not available in the drop down menu?  Any help would be much appreciated.  I have attached a screen shot for reference.[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are both a Condtions and an Actions tab, both have areas where you can specify rules. Under the Actions tab, where you specify what the discount actually is, can allow you to set quantity in cart as shown in balaji-kandasamy's image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to check the number of items in a cart. You can create new rule "`Total Items Quantity`" in `Shopping Cart Price Rule`

[image]

Comment: That is my problem there is no option to select Total Items quantity?  See my screen shot

Comment: please help me [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126123/how-to-integrate-imagemagick-to-magento)