# How to integrate ImageMagick to magento

Tags: magento-1.9, image, product-view

We need **product personalization** feature as [here](http://www.dailyobjects.com/custom-cases/apple/iphone-4-4s/custom-iphone-4-4s-case/slim), means we want customers to upload the product image and add text & color from product view page.

Then when customer buys product, we will send a product with same image. 
How we can use ImageMagick to implement this kind of feature. How to install imagemagick to magento site and use it.

**Edit**

I want to know how we can use imagemagick for creating particular feature.

Is we need place imagemagick folder in magento root or is we have to create any modules to implement the features. please give examples to implement some features.

**Edit 2**

as a 1st step, we are using magento default custom options to upload files [images] in product view page, now we want to replace the **Product images** by  **images uploaded through custom option**.

[image]

Comment: You can use this extension https://www.milople.com/magento-extensions/personalized-products.html

Comment: @BhupendraJadeja Thanks for link , but client is not ready to pay for any extension.

Comment: `This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed`... i guess its time to change this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below link for imagemagick installation

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php

```
<script>
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
/*
Design tool logic like add text, image, etc ....
*/
/*When user save design or add to cart user below for export canvas data into JSON and save it into database or json file*/
var json = JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON());
</script>
```

Below is the sample for getting data from JSON and providing data to imagemagick for text generation. You can also provide image data to imagemagick

```
<?php
/*$data will be json of the canvas which saved in database it json file*/
$personalizeData = json_decode($data);
/* process texts */
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($personalizeData->objects as $object) {
            if ($object->type == 'text' && (!empty($object->text) && trim($object->text) !='\n')) {
                if($object->fontFamily == 'arial'){
                    $font = 'fonts/Arial.ttf';
                }elseif($object->fontFamily == 'Verdana'){
                    $font = 'fonts/Verdana.ttf';
                }elseif($object->fontFamily == 'Times New Roman'){
                    $font = 'Times-Roman';
                }

                $font = fontPath.$font;
                $fontSize = $object->fontSize * $ratio;
                $left = $object->left * $ratio;
                $top = $object->top * $ratio;

                $w = $object->width * $ratio;
                $h = $object->height * $ratio;
                $rgb = hex2rgb($object->fill);
                if($rgb){
                    $rgb[] = $object->opacity;
                    $rgba = 'rgba('.implode(",",$rgb).')';
                }else{
                    $rgba = $object->fill;
                }

                $fontText = str_replace("'","'\\''",$object->text);
                if(!empty($fontText) || $fontText !='\n'){
                    /*Imagemagick command for generating text on image*/
                    exec("convert -size {$w}x{$h} -background 'transparent' -fill '{$rgba}' -font {$font} -gravity Center label:'{$fontText}' text{$i}.png");

                    if ($object->angle != '0') { /* rotate text and set updated left top */
                    /*Imagemagick command for generating text on image*/
                        exec("convert -rotate {$object->angle} -background transparent text{$i}.png text{$i}.png");
                        if($attSetName == 'Photo Collage'){
                            $left = $object->finalLeft * $ratio;
                            $top = $object->finalTop * $ratio;
                            $left+=600;
                            $top+=600;
                        }else{
                            $left = $object->finalLeft * $ratio;
                            $top = $object->finalTop * $ratio;
                        }
                    }
                    /*Imagemagick command for generating text on image*/
                    exec("/usr/local/bin/composite -geometry +{$left}+{$top} {$baseDir}text{$i}.png {$imgName} {$imgName}");
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        } 
?>
```

You can canvas.toSVG() also for getting SVG from the canvas with fabric.js

SVG is better option compare to json data and use for generating output.

```
https://inkscape.org/en/doc/inkscape-man.html
```

Inkscape has the command line option where u can convert SVG to PDF,PNG and to many other options.

Comment: Thanks a lot, nice links , 1st step,  I used custom options to upload image from product view page, but i want to replace the `product image` by `image uploaded by custom options` as [here](http://www.dailyobjects.com/custom-cases/letv/le1s-eco/custom-letv-le-1s-eco-cases/slim), can you please help me for this

Comment: They are not allow to change product image on above provided link. User can upload as many images they want. if you want change the product image with the help of custom option like IPhone model 4 , 4s, 5, 5s etc, you can add custom field in the admin with custom option and when user change the custom option product model you can change the phone model.

Comment: can you please help how to use the above code , is i need to place in view.phtml file ?

Comment: also is i need to run any commands to make this work ? is this is command in proepr for mat : convert -size {$w}x{$h} -background 'transparent' -fill '{$rgba}' -font {$font} -gravity Center label:'{$fontText}' text{$i}.png

Comment: you can use above script once user placed the order. On order success you can get the string of the canvas which is saved in database.

Comment: but how user can upload product image from product view page , also how user can add text to uploaded image.

Comment: When you are drawing any object on image with help of imagemagick you have to specify the position of that object.

Comment: okay, i saw in above code you wrote some code  to execute commands, is i need to execute those commands ? or if i just place the code in view.phtml, is that enough ?

Comment: because i already installed imagemagick in ubuntu server. i tried placing above phtml code and script in view.phtml , but i didt saw any option to add text to product image. is there any other code need to be add ?

Comment: There will be designtool on product detail page. like this http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink once user add the images and text and add product into cart and place order, during the order process you can use imagemagick and create the images based on users data. imagemagick is use with server side script.

Comment: @Ajay, can you help me to integrate the fabric js to my frontend? I am struggling a lot

Answer (score 7):

You can install imagick "easily" if you have access to the server with, one of the following commands:

- `pecl install imagick`
- `sudo apt-get install php5-imagick && sudo php5enmod imagick`
- or you do the "hard" way by compiling it yourself: https://community.webfaction.com/questions/6681/how-do-i-install-the-imagick-pecl-extension-for-my-php-53-application (use the current version though)

After image magick is installed, you can use the whole imagick lib: http://php.net/manual/de/book.imagick.php

Comment: Thanks, we installed in server,  which is better to use for `Product Personalization` feature - gd library, canvas or imagemagick ?

Comment: how i  can use complete   imagick lib , Is i need to download complete imagemagick from [here](http://php.net/downloads.php) & place in `magento lib` folder ? if not,  can you give one example.

Comment: imagick is a pecl extension, therefore "built in" (after you installed it with pecl). pecl should take care of all dependencies. And to answer your first question: imagick is far more powerful than GD and most of the time brings nicer results. But in the end is the tool you need the one which does the job.

Comment: Thats nice, can you please help me for uploading product images from `Product view page` with code. so that i can follow same & try for other parts of feature.

Comment: Uploading images is easy, you can just add (a couple of) custom option(s). But building a configurator is huge.

Comment: I used custom options to upload image from product view page, but i want to replace the `product image` by `image uploaded by custom options` as [here](http://www.dailyobjects.com/custom-cases/letv/le1s-eco/custom-letv-le-1s-eco-cases/slim), can you please help me for this.

Comment: can we use only `fiberjs` to achieve [this](http://www.dailyobjects.com/custom-cases/apple/iphone-se/custom-iphone-se-cases/slim) kind of functionality ? can we use `fiberjs` for design part & `imagemagick`  for saving the images in json format in database.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you achieve what with what?

Answer (score 5):

There is presently no free extension that meet your requirements. I suggest you look into some HTML5 Canvas javascript libraries to achieve at least the 'designer' portion of your requirement. There are currently a few dozen available freely. Here are a few of the most popular ones (according to # of Github watchers):

```
http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS
http://kineticjs.com/
http://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/
http://fabricjs.com/
```

Here is an exhaustive list with features and # of github watchers, links, links to sites and demos; compiled by the author of Fabric.js, @kangax. This is a great feature matrix:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqj_mVmuz3Y8dHNhUVFDYlRaaXlyX0xYSTVnalV5ZlE#gid=0

I imagine it would be fairly easy for you to develop one of these libraries into a fully-featured drop-in extension and contribute it back to the community.

Source [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/is-there-any-free-extension-available-for-designing-products-label-or-cover-in-m/%22Here%22) and Credit goes to @philwinkle

OR
You can use extension i found is [Milople Personalized Product](https://www.milople.com/magento-extensions/personalized-products.html/%22Milople%20Personalized%20Product%22)

Comment: Thanks a lot, nice links , 1st step,  I used custom options to upload image from product view page, but i want to replace the `product image` by `image uploaded by custom options` as [here](http://www.dailyobjects.com/custom-cases/letv/le1s-eco/custom-letv-le-1s-eco-cases/slim), can you please help me for this

Comment: You can use html input type file instead of custom options

Comment: if you update the answer with code, it will be very helpfull....

Comment: what you are using for product image

Comment: we are using magento default custom options to upload files [images] as [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/golden-waves-marble-texture-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) , you can see `file upload` otpions below price.