# gd library or image magick - which is better

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

We need `product personalization` feature, means we want customers to upload the product image and add text from frontend. then when he buy product, we will send a product with same image. 
[ ex product- T-shirts ].

For Provide this option for uploading an image and adding texts and color, is it better to use **g98 or image magick or canvas library ?** Is there any free extensions available ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to integrate ImageMagick to magento](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126123/how-to-integrate-imagemagick-to-magento)

Comment: You can this extension https://www.milople.com/magento-extensions/personalized-products.html