# How to overwrite magento1 image compression quality?

Tags: magento-1.9

Im having trouble finding the way to make some product images look better as they look dull and not sharp at all. I believe this has to do with the image compression code in Magento1.
I've realized it is quite a common issue as I found a lot of answers (all similar to each other) on this topic.

I've tried ->setQuality(100) in the catalog/product/list.phtml file but didnt work.
I also tried setting the property $_quality to 100 in Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php but didnt work either.

I'm running out of ideas as most of the answers I found are several years old.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try to use Imagemagick?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126123/how-to-integrate-imagemagick-to-magento

Comment: mmm...no. Sorry I should've mentioned I'm very new to PHP and Magento. What do you mean with Image?

Comment: This is a library which is used for images. Magento 1 use gd and imagemagick, so check if your server has installed image magick and select image magic option from magento 1 admin

Comment: Oh yeah...I have tried that too. I couldn't get it to work. Yes, we use both Gd2 and Imagemagick...but still doesnt work. Im losing my mind.